"was going to" versus "would"

That is what I thought was going to happen.

vs

That is what I thought would happen.

Which one is correct? Could both be wrong? Do they have the same meaning?

Welcome to ELL. What do you think? What leads you to think either may be right, or may be wrong? What research have you done? What did you find?

@PaulTanenbaum thanks. My research hasn't really  been helping me. I think it's correct because it just sounds right for both.

In your context I can't see any scope for a difference in meaning. But you might be able to differentiate between 1) I thought the dog was going to bite and 2) I thought the dog would bite. Similar, but not exactly the same as the difference between 3) Be careful! That dog will bite! and 4) Be careful! That dog is going to bite!

@FumbleFingers how about, the thing that you are doing right now is exactly what I thought was going to happen vs would happen.

I don't understand what you're asking. I just said in your context I can't see any scope for a difference in meaning, and so far as I can see what you're asking in the comment is for most purposes syntactically the same as what you asked in the actual question. The only difference being that the phrasing in the question could have "that" referring to something you expected that didn't happen, whereas in the comment it obviously is happening.

They're interchangeable in most cases, there may be some contexts where the nuances are a little different.

If you search here there are dozens of similar questions.
